# Changing dataTable with select

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have this command

```
dSet.Tables("Articles_table").Select("Nom = '" & sName & "'")("Quantité")
```

I wonder what do I put after the .select who return a row but not the method of it for me to change the code

"Nom" is a column
"Quantité" is also a column

Basicly what I want to do is to update a specific data in "Articles_table" Where the name is sName in the Quantité row

I've looked around but It seems I can't get the right keyword with google, ... , And I'm sure someone tried this before me so If it's a double post just point it out on me, if not I would be please to receive your help x)

Comment: Evitez d'utiliser des accent dans les noms de colonne des tables ;)

Comment: Avoid to use non english language on this site. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow/13684#13684

Comment: @Steve sorry didnt tought it was applying to my "String" I tought it was about the question and everythings not things like column name or table name, sorry

Comment: No, I was just answering to @Nadeem_MK comment. You could use whatever you like in your column names (Of course staying with english names sometime simplify your life in this world and there is no much that, we non-english speakers, could do about it beside trying to learn it)

Comment: Yea I get you I speak french and I think the same of you english is easier, but I'm in school, and the teacher want all of our "project" in french... in a way it's normal they don't want to loose the language, me I think it's staying behind the evolution but hey... not my decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method of a DataTable return an array of DataRows not a single DataRow

You need to add the indexer of the row

```
 Dim rows = dSet.Tables("Articles_table").Select("Nom = '" & sName & "'")
 If rows.Count > 0 Then
     Dim qta = rows(0)("Quantité")
     ....
 End If
```

Also I really suggest you to split your code in separate lines. You have an exception waiting to happen if the select doesn't return any row.

Comment: The multiselect is disable can I asumme the index of rows will always be zero ?

Comment: The arrays in NET always start at index zero. If you get just one row returned by Select then you have that row at index zero and Count will be 1. I don't understand what do you mean for multiselect.

Comment: It's an array of row, if I'm right and the select return more than 1 row there will be `rows(0)("")` and `rows(1)("")` now assuming the multiselect and there's no way that select return more than one row since "Nom" is a primary key in my table therefore unique, can I assume the `rows(Index)("")` will always be zero

Comment: If nom is the PrimaryKey, yes, if Count=1 then the index to use will be always zero, but be warned that Count=0 if the PrimaryKey doesn't exist and in this case you cannot access to the Rows(0)(....) element

Comment: Humm welll, it's not working x), If I doN,t secify the type of rows it's kinda working but I doN,t really like it because rows would be object no ?? and if I put type of DataRow or DataRowCollection they both give me error

Comment: The compiler is smart enough to figure out wath kind of object to assign to the resulting variables. What do you write when you try to specify the datatype?

Comment: Nvm, I forgot it was an array
`Dim dRows() As DataRow`

Comment: Last question, is there any modification like ReadOnly = false or anythings like that before performing the change on the table I saw that while I was searching

Comment: Not clear what do you mean, however I suggest to post a new question on that. You will get more audience.

Comment: Thank, will do if there's any problem